# Output conitinous nload results to a file

Tags: ubuntu, networking, monitoring

I am looking for a way to store the output of nload to a file, i've tried the standard

```
$ nload > file.log
```

but that turns into an empty file...

I would also like to keep the file small by overwriting older results

Anybody got an idea i am missing? Another piece of (open-source) software that can show me sorta the same but then static would be fine as well if that would be a better/easier solution...

Oh in case it matters i am running Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you solved the problem? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following command - it will also record any errors to the log file

```
$ nload >> file.log 2>&1
```

The output file will most likely will not be exactly human readable, since nload uses special characters to format the results on screen and draw pseudo graphs.

Comment: Once the command exists, the file is empty. How do we fix?